# How to solve CORS policy for HTTP status not ok?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm getting the following error :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/users/find-all/0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I know that there are a lot of questions of this type but I just can't solve the problem.
The backend is built with spring boot and the frontend is based on ReactJS.

```
@GetMapping("/find-all/{page}")
public PaginatedResultDto<UserDto> findAllPaginated(@PathVariable("page") int page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS) int numberOfElements) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, numberOfElements);
    return getBaseFacade().findAllPaginated(pageable);
}
```

And

```
getPaginatedResults = (pageIndex, resultsPerPage, endpoint, jwt) => {
    const resultsPerPagePath = resultsPerPage !== undefined ? "?numberOfElements=" + resultsPerPage : "";
    const endpointPath = BASE_URL + "/" + endpoint + "/find-all/" + pageIndex + resultsPerPagePath;
    return fetch(endpointPath, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + jwt
        })
    }).then( .. some error handling here )
```

I've configured `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in this way:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/find-all/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

And I have a `WebMvcConfigurer` too :

```
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type");
}
```

But I just can't solve this problem.. I've tried every solution from stack overflow but it didn't worked.

Comment: Unrelated, but setting CORs headers in the *client* is completely pointless. It says it's not getting an OK, check your request and response data.

Comment: is this resource server, authorization server or just server without any access rights- means all apis publicly accessible

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm getting a "TypeError: Failed to fetch" response when I'm logging it in browser console. The request is working with postman.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight You're likely getting an auth error on the pre-flight.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you a lot. This solved my problem :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `CorsConfigurationSource` bean, example is as below:

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                "http://localhost:8080",
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://localhost:4200"
                )
        );
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                        "Origin", "Cache-Control",
                        "Content-Type",
                        "Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Later in `*[Web/Resource]ServerConfigurerAdapter` add following code

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
         ...// Please complete this line to compile
    }
```